# How to insert a tab widget in split screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, split, extend

I have divided my android screen in two parts in one part i put my own app and in second part i want to insert a tab host, widget and it needs to extend my main class but the main class is already extended to some activity used by my first app. Is there any way to extend my main class by any other method ? Can anyone please help me in this ??

any kinda help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not possible. Android is not a web browser so you can't have more than one Activity to be on the forefront. Also it's not at all obvious what are you trying to do and achieve. Can provide some code examples, perhaps?

Comment: okkk... i want google map in first half and tabs in second half of screen.... nw is it possible to tht or is there any way to do that...??

Comment: Totally and that's how you should describe it in your question. So, basically you need to create a layout like this: outer LinearLayout (orientation vertical), then place MapView on top and tabs on the botton (http://goo.gl/IJVda). You don't have to use MapActivity for your activity it's merely a convenience